# using call function in map or forEach

Tags: javascript

When I want to map an array of numbers to strings I could do:

```
[1,2,3,4].map(function(n){return n.toString();})
```

I thought it would give the same result if I do:

```
[1,2,3,4].map(Number.toString.call)
```

But it does not.

Why? Shouldn't it work?

My real-life problem is that I have an array of Web-Workers and I want to terminate them all by doing:

```
webworkers.forEach(Worker.prototype.terminate.call);
```

Comment: Just now realized.. we can also do like this `([1,2,3,4] + "").split(",")`.. any comments?

Comment: That is a very short one. However my question is about using call in map or forEach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, for `function.call` to work, you would also need to supply the **thisArg** to the `function.call` as the context.

From MDN:

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its this value.

Try this:

```
webworkers.forEach(Worker.prototype.terminate.call, Worker.prototype.terminate);
```

Comment: Yes! I oversaw the need for `this`. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe using `Function.prototype` for `this` is even better. So we get:  `webworkers.forEach(Worker.prototype.terminate.call, Function.prototype)`

Comment: Of course, if it works please do use it. I just answered it with what I could muster up at that time. It's good to know this info!

Comment: No it is not good. It should be: `webworkers.forEach(Function.prototype.call, Worker.prototype.terminate)`

Answer (score 2):

You could just do with :

```
[1,2,3,4].map(String)
```

`String(1)` returns `"1"`.